# Kernels of Adjoints

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, inner-products

Let $A$ be an $m \times n$ matrix. Show that $\mbox{Ker} A = \mbox{Ker} (A^*A)$.
To do that you need to prove 2 inclusions, $\mbox{Ker} (A^*A)$ is a subset of  $\mbox{Ker} A$ and $\mbox{Ker} A$ is a subset of $\mbox{Ker} (A^*A)$.

Comment: If $A$ is any matrix, this is false. You want $\mbox{Ker} A^*A$ and not $\mbox{Ker} AA$.

Answer (score 1):

It $Ax=0$, I am sure you can prove that $A^*Ax=0$, This yields the latter inclusion.

For the former, all you need is the following observation:
$$
\|Ax\|^2=(Ax,Ax)=(x,A^*Ax)
$$
where $(x,y)$ denotes the usual inner product on the column vectors defined by
$$
(x,y)=x^*y=\sum_{j=1}^n\overline{x_j}y_j
$$
and $\|x\|=\sqrt{(x,x)}$ is the resulting Euclidean norm.

Comment: for showing the first inclusion, where does that <x,y> inner product come in?

Comment: If $A^*Ax=0$, then $(x,A^*Ax)=0$, But this is $\|Ax\|^2=0$. So $\|Ax\|=0$, which implies $Ax=0$. That's called the separation of the norm. It is because $\|Ax\|^2=\sum |x_j|^2$ is a sum of nonnegative terms. If it is equal to $0$, each term must be zero.